# Не работает "текстовая" половина кнопки в navigationBar

Tags: swift, navigationbar, ios10

Кнопка в navigation bar не срабатывает (метод хендлера не вызывается), если нажать на ее правую половину, где текст.

1. Если нажимать на ту половину кнопки где нарисован глобус, то иконка глобуса меняет свой цвет (этот момент показан на скрине ниже) и кнопка срабатывает
2. Если нажимать на правую половину кнопки, где располагается текст, то ничего не происходит - кнопка не срабатывает, иконка глобуса также цвет не меняет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка создается таким образом:

```
private func configureLanguageButton(_ title: String) {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconGlobe"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(Helper.Color.avocado, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightNavButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.sizeToFit()

    var rightButtonFrame = button.frame
    if let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height {
        rightButtonFrame.size = CGSize(width: rightButtonFrame.width, height: navBarHeight)
        button.frame = rightButtonFrame
    }
    let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

    // FIXME: не работает кнопка с той стороны текст, работает только есть нажать на иконку глобуса левее текста

    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
}
```

Метод configureLanguageButton вызывается во viewWillAppear контроллера. Тестирую в iOS12. Решение должно поддерживать iOS10+. Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Comment: Метод "rightNavButtonTapped" не вызывается при нажатии на текст? Проверьте границы superview, возможно правая часть кнопки ушла за его границы, там хэндлер не сработает тогда.